# How to pass complex object from jquery to action controller in tag <a>

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, controller

How to pass complex object from jquery to action controller in tag

I have a jquery code like this

```
function InitCell(row, column, value) {

    var MyPerson = new Object();
    MyPerson.ID = '123456789';
    MyPerson.FirstNmae = 'abc';
    MyPerson.LastName = 'def';

    var html = "<a href='/test/Index/person =" + MyPerson +"></a>";
}
```

In addition I have a action controller like this

```
public class testController : Controller

{
    //
    // GET: /test/

    public ActionResult Index(Person person)
    {
        return View();
    }

}

class Person
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public List<Person> Children { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you can do is make an `HTTP POST` request instead of `HTTP GET`.

```
$('#postLink').click(function() {
    var MyPerson = {
        ID: 1234,
        FirstName: 'abc',
        LastName: 'def'
    };

    $.ajax({
        data: MyPerson,
        url: $(this).attr('href'),
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json' /* this really is optional */,
        success: function (response) {
            return true;
        },
        error: function ( error ) {
            return false;
        }
    )};

    return false; /* required to stop event propagation */
});
```

Now you can define an HTML `<a>` element like so:

```
<a href="/test/Index" id="postLink">Ajax post the person to the server.</a>
```

Your controller should now be able to parse the `Person` object.

**Edit**: You might want to remove the `List<Person>` if you aren't passing it with each request. It would aid ASP.NET in identifying a complex type (`Person` in this case) as the data type of your request. It is generally better to create ViewModels for each of your views as well so that you have a strongly typed data context for your view.

```
class PersonViewModel
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: How do I contains the tag with a call to ajax?

Comment: You can wrap the entire JavaScript block in a click event handler. I'll update the JS code above with the example.

Answer (score 0):

You can't, as such. URIs are strings. If you want to pass data in them that isn't formatted as a string, then you have to serialise it to a string and then deserialise at the other end.

For general purposes, [JSON](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JSON) is a popular serialisation format, but remember that not all strings are URI safe so you will need to [encode the JSON text](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) before including it in a URI.

You just have three pieces of data though, so you could:

```
var html = "<a href='/test/Index/person/" +
           encodeURIComponent( MyPerson.ID ) + "/" +
           encodeURIComponent( MyPerson.FirstName ) + "/" +
           encodeURIComponent( MyPerson.LastName ) + 
           "></a>";
```

Or, if the data already exists on the server — just pass the ID value and then get the names from the database.

Answer (score 0):

A querystring takes parameters not the type of object you have so you will have to pass it as a querystring with delimited &

Example :

```
var html = "<a href='/test/Index/person?PersonId=123456789&FirtsName=Test......
```